# What's the recommended way to generate access keys for users?

Tags: api, security, sdk

Our users are developers that use our SDK in their apps. We need to generate possibly a set of access keys that they use to initialize our SDK.
The SDK is on their client-side so these access keys must be public.

An example of this might be the config keys that Firebase [uses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object) in their service.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend the usage JWT token with the combination of secrets. This way you can decode the JTW by the client secret key. A lot of companies use this way of SDK usage, for example Facebook and Twitter.